# Sklearn - StratifiedGroupKFold cannot be imported in JupyterNotebook Browser

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, importerror

I have been having issues importing `StratifiedGroupKFold` using JupyterNotebook.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedGroupKFold
```

> ImportError: cannot import name 'StratifiedGroupKFold' from 'sklearn.model_selection'

The weird thing is that I can import the module when I launch JupyterServer and run the notebook in PyCharm.

How can that be and how do I get to run import it in the default browser?

Answer (score 0):

May be you use a different environment in JupyterNotebook. Check your JupyterNotebook and pycharm environment, make sure they have the same environment

Comment: This answer is helpful but could provide more information to help understand and solve the question smartly. Don't hesitate to ask more questions and provide potential best practices to further develop the subject.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I guess there must be some conflicts with the versions. I'll highly recommend you to uninstall it and re-install it. This should resolve your bug.